# How to run a mongo query over a range of Time Interval?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, backend

I have a collection as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    “value” : 1,
    “time” : ISODate("2022-11-05T23:58:43.818+05:30")
},
{
    "_id" : 2,
    “value” : 1,
    “time” : ISODate("2022-11-06T23:58:43.818+05:30")
},
{
    "_id" : 3,
    “value” : 2,
    “time” : ISODate("2022-11-07T23:58:43.818+05:30")
},
{
    "_id" : 1,
    “value” : 1,
    “time” : ISODate("2022-11-05T23:58:43.818+05:30")
},
{
    "_id" : 1,
    “value” : 1,
    “time” : ISODate("2022-11-06T23:58:43.818+05:30")
},
{
    "_id" : 2,
    “value” : 1,
    “time” : ISODate("2022-11-05T23:58:43.818+05:30")
},
{
    "_id" : 1,
    “value” : 1,
    “time” : ISODate("2022-11-07T23:58:43.818+05:30")
},
```

I want to match all the documents within a day and group according to their id. I have tried using a query something like:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
        [
            {
                 "$match" : {
                     "time" :
                      {
                         $gte: ISODate("2022-11-01T01:42:08.136+05:30"),
                         $lte: ISODate("2022-11-02T01:42:08.136+05:30")
                      }

                     }
            },
            
           { 
            "$group" : 
                { "_id" : "$_id", 
                  "total" : { "$sum" : "$value"},
                  "first" : { "$min" : "$time"}
                    
                }
         }   
        ])
```

I want to write a query which groups documents within a day over an interval of one month.
For example:

```
{
                 "$match" : {
                     "time" :
                      {
                         $gte: ISODate("2022-11-01T01:42:08.136+05:30"),
                         $lte: ISODate("2022-11-02T01:42:08.136+05:30")
                      }

                     }
            },
```

```
{
                 "$match" : {
                     "time" :
                      {
                         $gte: ISODate("2022-11-02T01:42:08.136+05:30"),
                         $lte: ISODate("2022-11-03T01:42:08.136+05:30")
                      }

                     }
            },
```

```
{
                 "$match" : {
                     "time" :
                      {
                         $gte: ISODate("2022-11-03T01:42:08.136+05:30"),
                         $lte: ISODate("2022-11-04T01:42:08.136+05:30")
                      }

                     }
            },
```

Can we perform this operation in a single query?

I tried to run the query changing dates for an interval of one month. I want to do it by running a single query

Answer (score 0):

The `_id` field is a mandatory unique field, thus you cannot have such data.
Anyway, the aggregation pipeline would look like this

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $group: {
         _id: {
            _id: "$_id",
            day: { $dateTrunc: { date: "$time", unit: "day" } }
         },
         total: { $sum: "$value" },
         first: { $min: "$time" }
      }
   }
])
```